# Gson missing type parameter for ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, android, gson, proguard

I have this JSON object that contains list of "Contact" objects and it's child objects. I'm trying to use gson to get the `ArrayList` of `Model` objects in my JSON object but it returns missing type parameter exception. 
I'm getting the type like this:

`Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<tModel>>() { }.getType();`

And trying to get list like this:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();

ArrayList<Model> = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```

and in my proguard I kept the object package like this:

```
-keep class .somerepo.contactModel.** { *; }
```

I've seen similar questions but none of them solved my problem.

Here is the stacktrace:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 Process: ..., PID:
>   10360
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
>       at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(SourceFile:84)
>       at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.(SourceFile:62)
>       at semereop.contact.Contact$1.(SourceFile:184)
>       at somerepo.contact.Contact.geModelFromJson(SourceFile:184)

`geModelFromJson` method return `ArrayList<Model>` from gson.

Comment: please share the complete stack trace

Comment: @sidgate I updated the post :)

Comment: Can you post your model and the String that you  trying to convert?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add more information to your proguard file:

```
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. 
# Proguard removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes Annotation

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

For more details, check [this example](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) of Proguard file, provided in GSON repository.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: only -keepattributes Signature is needed when using the default proguard configuration.

Comment: only -keepattributes Signature is needed and worked for me